# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, react-redux

I am using MERN stack and Redux, when i try to fetch data from the MongoDb i keep getting the error 'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data' I have tried everything and can't figure out what is causing it. Can anyone see what i am missing? I am really new to this so please go easy on me. :) I have tried using data from an external JSON placeholder URL and it all pulls through as expected but when i switch to my own data it doesn't work.

```
My action is:

export const fetchSubjects = () => (dispatch) => {
  console.log("fetching called");
  fetch("/api/subjects/Subject")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((subjects) =>
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_SUBJECTS,
        subjects: subjects,
      })
    );
};


My model is:

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SubjectSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  summary: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  rating: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  author: {
    type: mongoose.ObjectId,
    default: this.users,
  },
  comments: [mongoose.ObjectId],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("subjects", SubjectSchema);


My api is:

const express = require("express");
const subjectRouter = express.Router();
const validateSubjectInput = require("../../validation/subjectVal");
const Subject = require("../../models/Subject");

subjectRouter.post("/subject", (req, res) => {
  // Form validation
  const { errors, isValid } = validateSubjectInput(req.body);

  if (!isValid) {
    console.log("Hitting");
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  Subject.findOne({ title: req.body.title }).then((subject) => {
    if (subject) {
      return res.status(400).json({ title: "Title already exists" });
    } else {
      const newSubject = new Subject({
        title: req.body.title,
        summary: req.body.summary,
        description: req.body.description,
      });
      newSubject
        .save()
        .then((subject) => res.json(subject))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  });
});

module.exports = subjectRouter;
```

Comment: I don't know this stack, but the error means that you're trying to parse something as JSON that isn't JSON. Check the data that you're parsing and make sure it's valid JOSN.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it sorted now. My get request was missing.